# Selenium sendkeys clearing out values when there are multiple sendkeys

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I have a selenium code trying to `sendkeys()`
I am using `firefox 35.0.1` and `selenium webdriver 2.44` and `eclipse Luna`

```
WebDriver d1 = new FirefoxDriver()
d1.get("www.xx.com")
WebElement username=d1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login_username']/input"))     
WebElement password=d1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login-assword']/input"))    
username.sendKeys("admin")      
password.sendKeys("welcome")
```

This enters the values and deletes it before I submit the values. 
tried adding

1. `d1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS)`
2. I've tried putting `Thread.sleep(x);`

but nothing is working please help me out.

Comment: are you trying to clear out the filed before sending new value?

Comment: can you share site to which you are testing?

Answer (score 1):

Try using Thread.sleep after clicking into the text field and then do a sendKeys(). 
If that doesn't work, try waiting until the document is loaded entirely. See below function:

```
void waitForPageLoad(WebDriver driver)
{   
ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pageLoadCondition = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() 
{       
public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver)
{
return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
}
};  
wait.until(pageLoadCondition);    
}
```